# How to proceed only after all onClick events finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, onclick

I have a wrapper for the HighCharts lib which autogenerates some code based on  [their API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts). In order to autogenerate this code I must export the HTML of the API website with ALL (recursive) the links (from the left side menu) expanded. This must be done recursive as new expanded links may have more not-yet-expanded links.

Right now I must *manually* proceed this loop from the Browser's Javascript console:

1. `$('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).click();`
2. `$('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).length`.  If zero, I am done. If none zero, then proceed again with 1).

I tried to automatize this like follows:

```
while ( $('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).length !== 0 ) {
    console.log('Doing a pass');
    $('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).click();
    console.log('Pass finished');
}
```

But it doesn't work as it goes to an endless loop. I guess this is because of onClick fires some async code (maybe an Ajax call?). Any idea how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "expanded"?

Comment: Each time you click on a `a.plus` link the menu 'div.collapsed' displays the inner possible new links for that menu you expanded. You know... the 3 dots of that site. That's why I must loop

Comment: Have you tried using `.each()` as suggested by @pandeyvishal1986 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it only expands the first pass of the 53 'a.plus' elements. Once that finishes, you query 'a.plus' again, and you have 216 new elements. That's why I need to make that recursive.

Comment: Does the 216 new elements include the previous 53 elements?

Comment: Now, they do not, as those new links (256) are those NEW links that were displayed once the 53 links were expanded/clicked. One a link is clicked/expanded, does not match the query 'a.plus'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127325/discussion-between-guest271314-and-mariano-martinez-peck).

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).length` is not going to change the value so please use

```
$('div.collapsed').find('a.plus').each(function(){
//some code
})
```

for more information regarding each. please check [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I loop to work and solve also the async issue? Of course, I can do `$('div.collapsed').find('a.plus').each(function(){ $(this).click(); });`. But that doesn't solve the fact that I must iterate that many times until there are no more 'a.plus' and the fact that likely the 'click' is doing something async.

Comment: You can use the `setInterval` function of javascript to perform an action in a specific interval of time. please refer to [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it this way:

```
/* Technically we could simulate the click on the links, like this:
$('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).click();
But that won't work as the clicks fire an async AJAX call so we don't know
when to expand their children. To make the recursion to work, I found there are many useful functions
in http://api.highcharts.com/resources/js/api.js
The function toogleExpand() allow us to pass a callback. That way, on callback, we expand again with children
making the recursion to work. */
function expandLinks( items ) {
    if (items.find('div[id$="-menu"]').length !== 0) {
        items.find('div[id$="-menu"]').each(function(){
            var link = $(this);
            toggleExpand(link.closest('.collapsed'),  function() {
          /* note that in this case we are making the recursion but only with the children of items */
          expandLinks( items.find('div.menuitem.collapsed') )
        });
            });
    } else {
    if( $('div.collapsed').find($('a.plus')).length == 0 ) {
      /* If there are no more links to open it means everything is ready so lets download the file */
      downloadDetailsDivContent();
    }
  }
}
```